# VSTS Azure File Copy task and ACL

Tags: azure-devops

I am using VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services, formerly known as Visual Studio Onine) for continuous deployment to an Azure VM using an Azure File Copy task in my build definition.

The problem I am having is that I have an ACL setup on the Azure VM that is only allowing connections from my office for Remote Powershell.

With the ACL in place, the Azure File Copy task fails with an error like "WinRM cannot complete the operation.  Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that the firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer."  With the ACL removed, everything works.

To be clear, this is not a problem with WinRM configuration or firewalls or anything like that.  It is specifically the ACL on the VM that is blocking the activity.

So the question is, how can I get this to work without completely removing the ACL from my VM?  I don't want to open up the VM Powershell endpoint to the world, but I need to be able to have the Azure File Copy task of my build succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an on-premises build agent that lives within your office's network and configure things so that the build only uses that agent.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/release/getting-started/configure-agents#installing

Comment: We are a small company with no on-prem servers so having a local build agent is presently not an option.  If having an on-prem build agent is the only option, I am willing to explore the idea.  However, I have to believe that others are building and deploying to Azure VMs with VSTS and there must me a solution to the problem that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Azure File Copy Task need to use WinRM Https Protocol, so when you enable the ACL, the Hosted Build Agent won't be able access to the WinRM on Azure VM and that will cause Azure File Copy Task fail.

> When copying the files from the blob container to the Azure VMs,
>   Windows Remote Management (WinRM) HTTPS protocol is used. This
>   requires that the WinRM HTTPS service is properly setup on the VMs and
>   a certificate is also installed on the VMs.

There isn't any easy workaround for this as I know. I would recommend you to [setup your own build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows) in your network that can access to Azure VM WinRM.